# Partial derivative equation with variable tranformation

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Solve, for $x>0$ and $y>0$:

$x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = y$

By introducing new variables: $x=u$ and $y=\frac{u}{v}$

I tried using the chain rule and obtained:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} \cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} $

$\iff \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}  $

And also:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = - \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} \cdot \frac{u}{v^{2}}$

Now sure if this is correct and how to proceed with this exercise. I tried rewriting the original equation with these two results but I'm not sure it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

$$x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = y$$
Let $x=u,y=\frac{u}{v}$, then $u=x,v=\frac{x}y$.
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\cdot 1+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\cdot \frac1y$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} =\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\cdot 0-\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\cdot \frac{x}{y^2}$$
Substituting into the original equation
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\cdot x+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\cdot \frac{x}y-\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\cdot \frac{x}{y}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\cdot x=y$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}=\frac{y}x=\frac1v\implies f=\frac{u}v+g(v)=y+g(\frac{x}y)$$
where $g$ is any differentiable function.

Answer (score 1):

The Lagrange-Charpit equations for the PDE $xf_x+yf_y=y$ are given by
$$
\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{df}{y}. \tag{1}
$$
The solution to $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}$ is $y=C_1x$, and the solution to $\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{df}{y}$ is $f=y+C_2$. Combining these two results, we obtain
$$
f(x,y)=y+\phi\left(\frac{y}{x}\right), \tag{2}
$$
where $\phi$ is an arbitrary differentiable function.